# Java - How to format a mix of strings and integers using printf() to get equal length in the output?

Tags: java, string, printf, decimalformat

I am having issues formatting this correctly:

```
       starting       mechanical cuchoo clock time [ 0:00:00], total drift = 0.00 seconds
    after 1 day      mechanical cuchoo clock time [23:59:00], total drift = 60.00 seconds
```

The correct formatting is:

```
   starting  mechanical cuckoo clock time [ 0:00:00], total drift = 0.00 seconds
after 1 day  mechanical cuckoo clock time [23:59:00], total drift = 60.00 seconds
```

I tried this and it actually works but is there a better way?

```
System.out.printf("%60s", this.getClockType() + " cuchoo clock time [" + time.formattedReportedTime() +
            "], " + "total drift = ");

System.out.printf("%s", fmt.format(time.getTotalDrift()) + "\n");
```

Comment: Show your format string, please. Do you specify a length for the last numeric field (and how)?

Comment: Try this  https://sharkysoft.com/archive/printf/docs/javadocs/lava/clib/stdio/doc-files/specification.htm

Comment: I added the code that make it display correctly but is there a better way to go about it. This seems like once I get passed the specified length "60" it will get messed up again

Answer (score 2):

Here a small snippet in addition to the answer from Caio.

```
String format = 
    "%12s  mechanical cuckoo clock time [%8s], total drift = %5.2f seconds%n";
System.out.printf(format, "starting", "0:00:00", 0.0);
System.out.printf(format, "after 1 day", "23:59:00", 60.0);
```

output

```
   starting  mechanical cuckoo clock time [ 0:00:00], total drift =  0.00 seconds
after 1 day  mechanical cuckoo clock time [23:59:00], total drift = 60.00 seconds
```

- `%12s` - the (first) parameter will be formatted as left padded string with 12 characters width
- `%8s` - as above, the (second) parameter with 8 characters
- `%5.2f` - the (third) parameter, which must be a floating point type, will be formated with a width of 5 charcaters and a precision of 2

Answer (score 0):

You should check this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) out. It's the Formatter Class doc it's super useful!

Comment: Thanks! It was very helpful